# Text removed from Matlab edit box when it's resized

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am building a GUI in Matlab (R2015a). The GUI has an edit box used as log output. When the main window is resized, all the text in the edit box disappears.

How can I fix this behaviour to keep the text?

Comment: Have you set a resize callback on your figure? Otherwise this shouldn't happen unless you manually reset the string to ""

Comment: Nope, the only setting I changed was the resizable behaviour to proportional in Tools ->GUI options

Comment: Can you create a minimal GUI with a single edit box to test if the behavior persists?

Comment: With a new GUI this behaviour didn't occur.As a workaround I have defined a callback which gets and then sets the text. This callback is executed when the main window is resized.

Comment: Hmm. Strange. Feel free to post your m-file here if you think that would help and its not too giant.

Comment: Do you have *any* callbacks defined for resizing?

Comment: I had the same problem, and I can reproduce it in a minimal fashion: `uicontrol('Style','edit')`.
At first When you resize the figure window, everything works fine, but after triggering the callback for the first time things start to go wrong! Then whenever the figure window is resized, the text in the edit box reverts to last time the callback was called, and the cursor jumps to the left end of the box.
I tried to implement your workaround, but it didn't change anything! I am in dire need of a solution to this problem myself, so any idea or even a crude workaround would be great!